# How to convert a SnowflakeCursor in to a pySpark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The result of sending an SQL to Snowflake is a SnowflakeCursor. How would I easily convert it into a pySpark dataframe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When using Databricks (https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/snowflake.html), we can use the spark.read to load the result of an SQL statement into a dataframe. Note that specifying the sfRole may be the key to gain access to your database objects.

```
 options = {
    "sfUrl": "https://yourinstance.snowflakecomputing.com/",
    "sfUser": user,
    "sfPassword": pw,
    "sfDatabase": "db",
    "sfSchema": "schema",
    "sfRole": "Accountadmin",
    "sfWarehouse": "wh"
  }

  df = spark.read \
    .format("snowflake") \
    .options(**options) \
    .option("query",  strCheckingSQL) \
    .load()
```